# Why doesn’t curl install and run on my 64-bit Windows 8 system but the 32-bit version works fine?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, curl

I almost gave up installing [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se) on my 64-bit Windows 8 system. I tried almost every single `.zip`, `.exe`, etc… [on this site](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), but none of them worked. I got this message every single time:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)

In my despair I tried a 32-bit installer and it worked like a charm. It’s running to full satisfaction now.

[image]

That leaves me to wonder; what did I do wrong with the 64-bit installers?

Comment: Are you 100% certain your running a 64-bit version of Windows?  What exactly were you downloading, I see several different versions, that could confuse the less informed.

Comment: Yep, see the edit.

Comment: I tried the ones under Win64 - Generic and the ones under Win64 - cygwin.

Comment: I had no problems running the version from [here](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/#downloads) which was linked to from the site you provided.  The cygwin binary would only work within cygwin obviously.  I just downloaded the .zip file since I didn't actually want to install it, there is no difference, there wasn't anything to "install" anyways

Comment: Ah, from there I went for the cURL Manager, but that's a pay link. The ones below actually work. Can I keep the 32-bit version or would it be better to uninstall and reinstall from this location?

Comment: Exactly which downloads did you try? Some of the Win64 bit ones under "Win64 - Generic" are for IA64 processors (Itanium 64-bit) which is NOT the same as x86-64. So you should be aiming for the "Windows 2000/XP x86_64" download links...

Comment: Why are you downloading a secondary application to manager what basically is files contained in a zip file?  Just download the .zip file and run curl don't make it complicated.

Comment: Those are the ones I didn't try because I thought those were not for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound: because I tried the IA64 ones which didn't install. So I figured I had to go for an application to do it for me. ;)

Comment: You really only need the 64bit version if you are doing massive downloads. I doubt you will notice a difference otherwise since the transfers are generally bound by the network speed rather than memory.

Comment: wget and curl are included in PowerShell under Windows 8.1 as you can see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364752/equivalent-of-wget-command-line-for-windows-8-1/46742133#46742133